Get Inbox Email using Nylas (only important email filter!)
Im using Nylas to curl the last 5 Emails for a Web Project.
The issue I have is that its list from all mails i got, the last 5 (Spam, Advertising or Buisness) mixed.
Is there maybe a nother solution?

const NYLAS_API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NYLAS_API_TOKEN; // Replace with your Nylas API Key

/**
 * Fetches messages for a given Nylas grant ID with an optional limit.
 * @param {string} grantId - The Nylas grant ID.
 * @param {number} [limit=5] - The number of messages to fetch (default is 5).
 * @returns {Promise<object>} - The response data from the Nylas API.
 * @throws {Error} - Throws an error if the API call fails.
 */
export const getMessages = async (grantId, limit = 5) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.us.nylas.com/v3/grants/${grantId}/messages`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, application/gzip',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${NYLAS_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        params: {
          // Filtering for important emails and excluding promotional category emails
          //search_query_native: 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', //NOT WORKING
          //in: IMPORTANT, //NOT WORKING
          limit
        }
      }
    );
    return response.data.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(
      console.error(err)
    );
  }
}; ```


Maybe Aurinko API will cooperate better?
https://docs.aurinko.io/unified-apis/email-api
